# ruby bundler not installing gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle

I'm trying my first Ruby app - unfortunately due to constraints in our deployment environment, it doesn't have access to external ruby gems. Thus I package them locally to install via bundler.

Here's my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rack', '=2.0.3', :path => "/opt/app-root/src/gems"
gem 'puma', '=3.10.0', :path => "/opt/app-root/src/gems"
```

My gems are present in /opt/app-root/src/gems and when I run `bundle install --local --path ./bundle --deployment` the output is so:

```
Using puma 3.10.0 from source at `/opt/app-root/src/gems`
Using rack 2.0.3 from source at `/opt/app-root/src/gems`
Using bundler 1.13.7
Bundle complete! 2 Gemfile dependencies, 3 gems now installed.
Bundled gems are installed into ./bundle.
```

Yet using gem list shows them not present (nor do any expected commands work, e.g. bundle exec rackup).

The ./bundle directory has nothing in it other than this empty directory structure:
    /opt/app-root/src/ruby/bundle/ruby/2.4.0

Can anyone help, what am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you have in `/opt/app-root/src/gems`?  The `gem` file itself or the unpacked folder?  Per the Bundler documentation, these must be the unpacked/extracted library.  http://bundler.io/v1.5/gemfile.html

Comment: You could also run your own gem server in `/opt/app-root/src/gems`: `gem server`, then configure bundler to look there. I'm not sure how to do that but this page might help: http://bundler.io/v1.16/bundle_config.html

Comment: Thanks Joe - I simply failed to rtfm - completely missed the point they need to be extracted!

Comment: Actually, this worked for rack - rackup works and appears here once installed by bundle:
/opt/app-root/src/ruby/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/rackup

But puma isn't touched - rackup is the only binary installed.

Comment: Additionally neither rack or puma exist when I list gems (gem list). Both install fine if I use gem install, but I need to use bundle.

Comment: Ok this works for puma, by adding the full extracted gem path (although I don't understand why rack worked either way!)


gem 'rack', '=2.0.3', :path => "/opt/app-root/src/gems/rack-2.0.3"
gem 'puma', '=3.10.0', :path => "/opt/app-root/src/gems/puma-3.10.0"